# CSS priorities and targeting specific elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

My question should be pretty strait forward. For some reason I can't wrap my head around it today.

I'm making a menu with a structure like so

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu Item</a>
            <div class="inner">
                <a href="#">Login</a> 
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to target the login link using the following css selector:

```
.inner a{}
```

The selector is working, however the following selector is taking css presidence, and overriding the above selector:

```
li.menu-item a{}
```

I'm totally baffled. Why would the second selector take style preference over the first? How would you guys recommend I target the above "a" elements?

Comment: Which selector comes last?

Comment: @j08691 Doesn't matter, a rule with two type selectors and a class selector beats a a rule with one and a class selector, whatever the order.  Read up on [CSS Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity).

Comment: @robertc - thanks, but I know all about CSS specificity. I was simply asking a question.

Comment: In the line-up, the .inner a{} came last.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why would the second selector take style preference over the first?

Because the second selector is more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the first. The first contains **one** class and **one** type selector while the second has **one** class and **two** type selectors.

To calculate specificity, think of an selector as consiting of four numbers, all starting at **(0,0,0,0)**

- Inline styles have the highest specificity and would take the place of the first number **(1,0,0,0)**.
- ID's count as the second number **(0,1,0,0)**
- Classes, [pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-classes) ([other than `:not()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879843/calculating-css-selector-specificity-for-not-pseudo-class/16228059#16228059)) and [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) count as the third number **(0,0,1,0)**
- [Type selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#type-selectors) and pseudo-elements - e.g. `div {}` or `::after{}`  count as the fourth **(0,0,0,1)**

Also:

- The [universal selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#universal-selector) `*` has no effect on a selectors specificity.
- [Combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#combinators) like `+`, `~` and `>` also have no effect on specificity.
- [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) rules almost always take precedence; though they don't affect the four numbers associated with a selectors specificity. Only another `!important` rule can override a previously defined one. [The exception is when the previously defined `!important` rule has a more specific selector.](http://jsfiddle.net/tj92t/2/) Here, the normal rule of specificity (described above) apply.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post. Info about CSS I obviously need to store away.

Answer (score 3):

CSS Selectors have a "weight" system attached to them,

- Element, Pseudo Element: d = 1 – (0,0,0,1)
- Class, Pseudo class, Attribute: c = 1 – (0,0,1,0)
- Id: b = 1 – (0,1,0,0)
- Inline Style: a = 1 – (1,0,0,0)

so your first selector has a score of (0,0,1,1)
while your second selector has a score of (0,0,1,2) which is higher and thus takes precedence

Answer (score 1):

That is because li.menu a contains three parts to idendtify the element:  the parent element (li), the parent class (menu-item) and the element (a).  Your intended selector only has two, so you could modify it to this:

```
li.inner a{}
```

And it should work.

Edit:

I knew I'd answered this before: [Why does my HTML not use the last style defined in the CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641729/why-does-my-html-not-use-the-last-style-defined-in-the-css/13641874#13641874)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The following selector is working for me, div.inner a{}

Answer (score 0):

CSS precedence is won by the DOM object with the highest specificity.

So what earns specificity?

```
Element Selector -- 1
Class Selector -- 10
ID Selector -- 100
Inline Selector -- 1000
```

In your example: 
.inner a would be 11 points

```
a(1) + .inner(10) = 11
```

li.menu-item a is 12 points

```
li(1) + .menu-item(10) + a(1) = 12
```

So that's why the second will be what's shown.  To make the correct style show, just make it more specific, for example use 
    .menu-item .inner a

There's a very good article about this here.
http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the CSS only to the anchors inside each element, like this:

```
li.menu-item > a{}
.inner > a
```

Doing it this way, the rules of "li.menu-item a" will not interfere in the other anchor.