# Why does bootstrap accept form styling for only one highly specific css classes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, input

I have a jsbin with a table of inputs, using bootstrap. What confuses me is that the style with

```
input.someClass {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

is applied, as expected, but

```
.anotherClass {
    background-color: green;
}
```

is not applied to my input elements. What is the reason for this? For reference, check out http://jsbin.com/enaris/3/edit

Comment: one is more specific than the other, `.something` is more generic than `.this.this.that.more`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the *reason* for this?

It's simply a matter of [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) - the first selector has a [type selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#type-selectors) attached to the class name whereas the second selector only has a single class. The second selector is therefore more specific and takes precedence.

This is migrated from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445376/css-priorities-and-targeting-specific-elements/16445459#16445459) of mine, it may help:

You can think of specificity as four numbers, starting with (0,0,0,0):

- !important rules always take precedence, only another !important rule
  can override a previous one (its an accessibility feature of CSS,
  designed to override the UA stylesheet)
- The universal selector (*) has a specificity of 0
- Combinators like `+` and `~` also have no specificity
- Inline styles have the highest specificity (other than !important)
  and count as the first number (1,0,0,0)
- ID's (`#test`) count as the second number in the above set (0,1,0,0)
- Classes, pseudo-classes and attribute selectors are the third number
  (0,0,1,0)
- Type selectors and psuedo-elements (e.g. - `<p>` & `::after`) take place of the
  fourth number, and are the least specific
- Remember that if two rules have the same specificity and specify the
  same property the latter in the stylesheet will win

Based on the above, the first selector has a specifictiy of (0,0,1,1) while the second only has (0,0,1,0)

Answer (score 2):

CSS rules are applied from least specific to most specific.

You have:

```
Least Specific    More Specific                  Most specific
.anotherClass     input[type=...] (bootstrap)    input.someClass
```

So, in your example `b-cell` is more specific than bootstrap styles and `a-cell` is less.

You can force `a-cell` to take precedence with `!important` (but use `!important` with caution, as it might become a debugging hell):

```
.a-cell {
  background-color: green !important;
```